# Python: Get the total hour from start time column and end time column in CSV file

Tags: python, database, csv, dataframe, time

I have 2 column 'Start' and 'End' in file CSV. I  want to write a column name 'Total' with the data as total hours.

My data:

```
Start   End 
-----------
16      18  
 3      15  
13      23  
22      15  
 9       1
```

The data I want:

```
Start   End     Total
----------------------
16      18       2  
 3      15      12
13      23      10
22      15      17
 9       1      16
```

Comment: please check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
dif=(df['End']-df['Start'])
df['Total']=np.where(dif>0,dif,24+dif)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Start  End  Total
0     16   18      2
1      3   15     12
2     13   23     10
3     22   15     17
4      9    1     16
```

Comment: I am glad to help you